# how to shutdown akka remote deployed actors and router?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am trying to use Scala and Akka(2.3.8)

Code

```
object Main extends App {
  args match {
    case Array("worker") => {
      startWorker
    }
    case Array("service") => {
      startService
    }
    case _ => {
      println("Invalid")
    }
  }

  def startWorker: Unit = {
    println("Remote is Ready !!!")
    ActorSystem("server", ConfigFactory.load("worker.conf"))
  }

  def startService: Unit ={
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("study", ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
    val master = system.actorOf(Props[Master], "study")

    for (i <- 1 to 100) {
      master ! i
      Thread.sleep(5)
    }
    master ! "Stop"
    system.shutdown()
  }
}

class Master extends Actor {
  val router = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props[ServerActor]), "worker")
  def receive ={
    case "Stop" =>
      router ! Broadcast(PoisonPill)
    case x => router.forward(x)
  }
}

class ServerActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case x => {
      println("got message from remote " + x)
    }
  }
}
```

works, but I had this logs

> [WARN] [07/01/2015 00:16:11.532] [server-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-13] [LocalActorRefProvider(akka://server)] Unknown message [DeathWatchNotification(Actor[akka.tcp://study@127.0.0.1:2551/user/study/worker#1059230782],true,false)] received by [Actor[akka://server/remote]]
>   [ERROR] [07/01/2015 00:16:11.604] [server-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] [akka.tcp://server@127.0.0.1:2552/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Fstudy%40127.0.0.1%3A2551-0/endpointWriter] AssociationError [akka.tcp://server@127.0.0.1:2552] <- [akka.tcp://study@127.0.0.1:2551]: Error [Shut down address: akka.tcp://study@127.0.0.1:2551] [
>   akka.remote.ShutDownAssociation: Shut down address: akka.tcp://study@127.0.0.1:2551
>   Caused by: akka.remote.transport.Transport$InvalidAssociationException: The remote system terminated the association because it is shutting down.
>   ]

Why? 
I don't understand that treatment method.Please tell me how to deal with this problem.